# NeutralinoJs is not working in Raspberry Pi 3 (Using 32bit Raspbian OS)

Tags: raspberry-pi3, raspbian, neutralinojs

I have to create a simple GUI app with 3 screens so I decided to use more light-weight and less ram memory using techstack. I tried PyQT, Java swing, JavaFx all these are taking too much memory.

But neutralino impressed me. It is taking 1.5MB to build size and consuming 3.5 MB of RAM. So I tried to use neutralino in my Raspberry Pi 3 that has Raspbian OS (32bit).

neutralino Installation is a success
I created the app using `$neu create <app-name>` command

following are not working for me

`$neu listen` not working, unfortunately, there is no log.
`$neu run` not working and no logs

I am trying to get logs, if I get that I will update the question. I am a noob in NeutralinoJS. So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried it on Raspi Pi 4b: "unsupported platform or CPU architecture: linux arm"

Answer (score 0):

The best way to move forward is to report the issue on the [Github Page](https://github.com/neutralinojs/neutralinojs/issues).
There will likely not be a fix you can do yourself. For right now, you should try a different OS either on a USB or on your computer.